# Storyboard Segue

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.ios

Estou a criar um pequeno exemplo de um aplicativo para iOS usando o Visual Studio 2015 no Windows 10.

No entando, sempre que abro o `Main.storyboard` pelo designer e clico em um dos `UIStoryboarSegue` a propriedade `Segue` fica como se nada tivesse sido selecionada.
Ficando o código Xml do componente da seguinte forma:

```xml
<segue id="241" destination="12" kind="popoverPresentation"/>
```

Altero manualmente para

```xml
<segue id="241" destination="12" kind="presentation" modalTransitionStyle="flipHorizontal"/>
```

Se alterar manualmente o `kind` ele aceita e funciona, porém sempre que volto no designer do `storyboard` e clico no `segue` ele muda a propriedade `kind` para `popoverPresentation`.

Isso é um bug do Xamarin?
Teria algum *fix* para corrigir esse problema?

Comment: Estou com o mesmo problema no visual studio. Quando utilizei o Xamarin Studio no MAC, funcionou.

Comment: Eu resolvi atualizando para uma versão alpha.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parece que é um [bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=segue) mesmo da versão stable do Xamarin.

Resolvi atualizando o Xamarin para versão Alpha.

Para atualizar o Xamarin, pelo Visual Studio 2015, para uma versão Alpha, basta ir no menu `Tools | Options -> Xamarin | Other`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

OBS: A versão do `Xamarin Studio` no Mac também tem que ser atualizada para a mesma versão.